# How do I structure a multiple choice test bank schema with different types

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design my schema for a multiple choice question bank with different question types. Questions can have diagrams embedded in them. I have done the following but not sure if its the correct approach. I'm still in the process of learning SQL.

**1.** Question Table
-ques_id
-ques_description
-ques_type

**2.** Type Table

-type_id
-type_description

**3.** Diagram Table

-diag_id
-
diag_url

**4.** Ques_Diagram Table

-qd_id
-
ques_id
-diag_id

**5.** Answer Table

-answ_id

-answ_description

**I'm not sure how I can structure the following table**
one answer can be used by several questions.

**6.** QuestionAnswers Table

-quesans_id

-ques_id

-ans_id

-Is correct (bool)

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you continue learning SQL, as any answer you get now might not be the solution you actually need when your scheme is complete.

Have you tried your solution? According to what you describe here, your 6th table is quite OK, and will allow you getting the relevant answers for each question (or vice versa).

Comment: I have tried it but I was not sure if the boolean variable was appropriate in the 6th table

Comment: It is. That schema allows you to get, for any question, all the possible answers, either right or wrong. It does not mean, of course, that the schema enforces all the conditions you would like it to have. For example, if you allow only one correct answer per a question, this schema will not enforce it; but neither does it enforce other requirements, like having each question ending by a question mark. Some properties are better be enforced programmatically.

Comment: You opened up my mind about some properties that can be manipulated programmatically. I will consider your idea. Thank you for the help